# ag-grid onFilterModified

Tags: filter, ag-grid

How to show current rows in ag grid.

I am using below code which gets executed when onFilterModified is called.

```
let tempRowCount = this.api.getModel().getRowCount();
console.log("temp count changin",tempRowCount);
//   alert("row count"+tempRowCount);
this.noOfRowsVisible = String(tempRowCount);
```

Then I am binding the variable **noOfRowsVisible** to view(HTML).
The problem is I am able to get filtered rowcount in console as defined above in the method. But view is not updated with new value of **noOfRowsVisible**.
Please help someone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I am not able to call any method from onFilterModified of ag-grid

Comment: Does your `console.log` ever print out to the console?

Comment: Yes..it does...but when I am checking the value of noOfRowsVisible in some other method, it is still zero.